# Directed line segments

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

[image: This is the question]

The above question got me thinking how to resolve this AFTER ofcourse substituting the values.. tks

Comment: For example, by definition: $\vec{OA}+\vec{AB}=\vec{OB}$. So $\vec{OA}+\vec{AB}+\vec{BD}=\vec{OD}$. Add and solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\vec{OD}=\vec{OA}+\vec{AB}+\vec{BD}$.

Comment: so my answer would be h=5?